# Correct XPath syntax when XML child element contain namespace

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have this XML file containing information of changed attributes as follows:

```
<xf:Data xmlns:xf="uri:com.data/Data">
 <xf:ElementId>XF42591459</xf:ElementId>
 <xf:ElementDescription>Part number 42591459</xf:ElementDescription>
 <xf:StockData>
  <xf:Available>YES</xf:Available>
  <xf:StockCount xmlns:diff="uri:com.data/diff" diff:oldcount="200">197</xf:StockCount>
 </xf:StockData>
</xf:Data>
```

I would need to find out the value of oldcount but I'm puzzled since the xmlns-definition within the child element confuses me.

I've tried using XPath `/xf:Data/xf:StockData/xf:StockCount/@diff:oldcount` but it doesn't seem to work. If `xmlns:diff="uri:com.data/diff"` would be part of `<xf:Data...>` it would seem to work just fine.

Comment: Could you try the following syntax: /*[local-name()='Data']/*[local-name()='StockData']/*[local-name()='StockCount']/@*[local-name()='oldcount'] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `/xf:Data/xf:StockData/xf:StockCount/@diff:oldcount` will work, but only if you tell your XPath processor what namespaces the "xf" and "diff" prefixes refer to. The way you do this varies from one XPath processor to another. (You don't have to use the same prefixes as the source document uses, any prefix that maps to the right URI will do)